# Pyinstaller: how to include file

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to make simple project with python then compile it with pyinstaller

my code is :

```
# coding: utf-8

f = open("1.txt")
print f.read()
```

but it's showing to me after I compile it this error :

```
No such file 1.txt
```

So my question is how to include file and image to pyinstaller

Comment: specify the file's full path.

Comment: @AvinashRaj C:\Users\deounix\Desktop\tt\striker\1.txt

Comment: @AvinashRaj also C:\Users\deounix\Desktop\tt\striker\1.png

Comment: @AvinashRaj if I specify file path it's working but after I compile it to .exe file it's wouldn't  run again

Comment: try to locate files in same folder with executed script

Comment: @Andersson it's didn't work the problem is when I compile the project it's didn't include files to .exe file

Comment: it should not include files that script will operate with- it should include packages to import in code

Comment: @Andersson What should I do is there any code or something that is help me ?